# Getting everything about the User that has specific skill, Many-to-Many filtering

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to filter users from a database based on their knowledge for example some users know C# others C++ but there are users that know both languages.

My models generate by Database first approach look as such

```
public partial class Entity
    {
        public Entity()
        {
            Knowledge = new HashSet<Knowledge>();
        }

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Passwd { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public int Apartment { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Knowledge> Knowledge { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class Knowledge
    {
        public int KnowledgeId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string SkillName { get; set; }

        public virtual Skill SkillNameNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Entity UsernameNavigation { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Skill
    {
        public Skill()
        {
            Knowledge = new HashSet<Knowledge>();
        }

        public string SkillName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Knowledge> Knowledge { get; set; }
    }
```

As mentioned trying to get for example users only know C# where `skill` is passed into Controller

```
                var l = ctx.Entity.Select(
                    c => new Entity()
                    {
                        Knowledge = (ICollection<Knowledge>)c.Knowledge.Where(s => s.SkillName == skill),
                        Username = c.Username,
                        City = c.City,
                        Country = c.Country,
                        Street = c.Street,
                        Email = c.Email,
                        Apartment = c.Apartment
                    }
                    ).ToList();
```

gives all the users in the database but for users that don't know C#, it returns an empty `Knowledge` list. The above code gives the same output as below

```
var l = ctx.Entity.Include(u => u.Knowledge.Where(k => k.SkillName == skill)).ToList();
```

so I thought maybe based on the latter one I can eliminate Users with `Knowledge.Count == 0`

```
var l = ctx.Entity.Include(u => u.Knowledge.Where(k => k.SkillName == skill)).Where(k => k.Knowledge.Count != 0).ToList();
```

But still, I get the same output, I see there are many posts created related to this problem I went through most of them yet I am still lost.

Thanks to anyone who takes their time to help.

**Edit**
Essentially SQL Query I am trying to write is as below but I couldn't make it work using `FromSqlRaw` method or by using LINQ

**Edit** Changed the query according to advice of @Ceemah Four

```
SELECT * FROM Entity
LEFT JOIN Knowledge ON Entity.Username = Knowledge.Username 
LEFT JOIN Skill ON Knowledge.Skill_name = Skill.Skill_name
WHERE Entity.Username IN (SELECT Entity.Username FROM Entity 
                        LEFT JOIN Knowledge ON Entity.Username = Knowledge.Username 
                        LEFT JOIN Skill ON Knowledge.Skill_name = Skill.Skill_name
                        WHERE Skill.Skill_name IN ('C#'))
```

Comment: Can you not use left joins with an IN clause. That should give you the users for all/any skills. that can easily translated to Linq